# Azure DevOps gulp step fails with Local modules not found

Tags: npm, gulp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure DevOps build step that runs gulp for an angularjs application. I set the Gulp file path to point to the `GulpFile.js` the referenced task should bundle the app and put the files into a zip file in the solution folder. This works fine when I run this locally in Visual Studio.

The error I am getting during the build is the following:

> 2019-07-08T15:54:56.5447810Z Task         : Gulp
>   2019-07-08T15:54:56.5447868Z Description  : Node.js streaming task
>   based build system 2019-07-08T15:54:56.5447921Z Version      : 0.141.2
>   2019-07-08T15:54:56.5447966Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2019-07-08T15:54:56.5448064Z Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=634721)
>   2019-07-08T15:54:56.5448113Z
>   ============================================================================== 2019-07-08T15:54:57.7184034Z
>   [command]C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd Export
>   --gulpfile C:\a_work\15\s\UI\Gulpfile.js 2019-07-08T15:54:58.6597682Z [[90m15:54:58[39m] Local modules not found in C:\a_work\15\s\UI
>   2019-07-08T15:54:58.6597830Z [[90m15:54:58[39m] Try running: npm
>   install

Does this error occur because Node is missing the necessary modules to bundle the app. Can I make the bundle task call npm install for the app before continueing the task?

Comment: Why not just add `npm install` task before this task?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem in case you want to create an answer

Comment: Great! I added this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a task just do the `npm install` before the gulp build:

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    command: install
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    verbose: false
```

Comment: Can you please share task for gulp with max old space?

Answer (score 0):

The azure devops agent has its own `node.exe` that gets installed in `...\_work\_tool\node\`(node bin location) e.g. `D:\azure_devops_agent\_work\_tool\node\10.24.1\x64\node.exe`.

If your `package.json` (for `npm`) or `gulpfile.js`(for `gulp`) is in subfolders you should provide the path to that.

In case, you are working with classic pipelines and using `command line` task, it should be provided this way before running `gulp` commands:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\subfolder
REM ..any gulp command...
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your tasks in the same job and not in separate jobs.  That is, run `Npm@1` task in the same job right before the `gulp@0` task, otherwise the checkout step will clean the entire npm install task.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33432636)