# gulpfile.js is not run on Azure VSBuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a .NET MVC project that executes the gulpfile.js after each build `/// <binding AfterBuild='default' />`. This works well if I build the project locally in Visual Studio. But I have to set up the auto build on Azure Pipeline after each commit. The `VSBuild@1` task completes successfully but the gulpfile.js does not get executed.

gulpfile.js

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='default' />
'use strict'
//include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'),

//include plugins
templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
rimraf = require('rimraf'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
gutil = require('gulp-util'),
path = require('path');

//concatenate & minify JS Files
function scripts() {
    return gulp.src([...])
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js')) 
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Build/js'))//put main.js in this folder
}

exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.default = gulp.series(scripts);
```

Azure pipeline yaml

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Gulp is preinstalled on Microsoft-hosted agents. You could try to add a [Gulp task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gulp?view=azure-devops) after  the ```VSBuild@1``` task to execute the gulpfile.js.

Comment: I did try adding the gulp task. This is what i am getting.. C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\npm\prefix\gulp.cmd --gulpfile D:\a\1\s\src\...\gulpfile.js" 
[19:28:42] Local modules not found in D:\a\1\s\src\...\PackageTmp 
[19:28:42] Try running: npm install 
##[error]gulp failed with error: The process 'C:\npm\prefix\gulp.cmd' failed with exit code 1 
Finishing: gulp

Comment: Hi Ben, Does my answer work for you? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Comment: Hi Edward, I couldn't get the gulp task to work but I did figure out why the pipeline task gives me the error. I think it's because it's not running on the right directory. So that i ended up doing was writing a batch file on the webserver and run the npm install and gulp.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you can add a task just do the npm install before the gulp build:

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    command: install
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    verbose: false
```

See thread: [Azure DevOps gulp step fails with Local modules not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938894/azure-devops-gulp-step-fails-with-local-modules-not-found) for more details.

**Update**>>
The directory of artifact is [$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services), so it should be D:\a\1\a. If the js file is not included in the artifact, you could use the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the js file to this directory before the [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you. I am finally able to get the gulp task to run. But why the minimized js file is not included in the artifact?? [18:49:33] Working directory changed to D:\a\1\s\src\
[18:49:34] Using gulpfile D:\a\1\s\src\gulpfile.js
[18:49:34] Starting 'default'...
[18:49:34] Starting 'cleanjs'...
[18:49:34] Finished 'cleanjs' after 7.14 ms
[18:49:34] Starting 'htmlTemplates'...
[18:49:36] Finished 'htmlTemplates' after 1.9 s
[18:49:36] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:49:48] Finished 'scripts' after 12 s
[18:49:48] Finished 'default' after 14 s
Finishing: gulp

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to have Azure to deploy the artifacts to my webserver. Then I have a batch file to unzip and move the built files to the IIS directory. Then in the batch file, I have the following:

```
CD <<IIS directory>>
npm install
gulp --gulpfile "path\to\gulpfile.js"
```

This way, it executes the gulfile.js to combine and minimize the javascript files when it deploys to IIS. The reason it did not work with Azure pipeline was that it was not in the correct directory to find the gulpfilejs path

Comment: Gladly to hear that you have resolved this issue and shared your solution below. You could mark your Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues, thank you.